# Need help manipulating class with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class

I need help with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fav").click(function() {

        $(".fav").removeClass("fav").addClass("fav_");
    });

    $(".fav_").click(function() {

       $(".fav_").removeClass("fav_").addClass("fav");
   });

});
```

On click in `.fav` `div`, he transforms to `.fav_` and vice-versa. Ok, but the problem is: 
If you click one time to `.fav` class, he transform to `.fav_`. But if you click one time more, he don't transform again to `.fav`.

I tried put one var to check. ex:

- if clicked one time: `fav=true`
- if clicked two times: `fav=false`

but it doesn't work.

I understand jQuery, but my usual language is PHP, perhaps thence the difficulty.

Comment: If the user clicks a `.fav` element, should  *all* (this one, and all others) change class to `.fav_`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to the DOM elements in a variable, and use that. This way you don't have to perform the jQuery selector again.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var favs = $(".fav");

  favs.click(function() {
     favs.toggleClass("fav");
     favs.toggleClass("fav_");
  });
});
```

You can also use the [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) method to add/remove the classes. If it tests with `fav` then it should toggle back and forward between `fav` and `fav_`. So there is no need for IF statements.

EDIT:

If you want to toggle the showing of the background image, then you don't have to remove the `fav` CSS class. Just toggle `fav_` as it's background will override `fav` because it's lower in the CSS source.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".fav").click(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass("fav_");
   });
});
```

Comment: I set up an example: [link]http://retroplus.qlix.com.br/fav.php

One time: sucess!
Two times: fail! kkk

I think it's best to see what I want.